# node.js: using http-proxy with http agent causes to file descriptors leak

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, proxy, http-proxy

I'm using [http-proxy](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy) to create websocket-proxy. Proxy works fine, but after a while of starting the process I'm facing with the problem: the process starts keeping a lot of open sockets. I can see that via lsof command - a lot of sockets like this:

```
> lsof -p 16
node     16 root  254u     sock       0,9      0t0 390707607 protocol: TCPv6
node     16 root  256u     sock       0,9      0t0 390351892 protocol: TCPv6
node     16 root  262u     sock       0,9      0t0 390313109 protocol: TCPv6
```

Also, I can see these sockets in proc:

```
> ls -haltr /proc/16/fd
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec 22 16:22 367 -> 'socket:[390186932]'
```

I tried to add some restrictions to http-agent like [maxFreeSockets](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#agentmaxfreesockets) and timeout, but it doesn't help. Maybe you have any ideas about this problem.

P.S. Also I tried this [fix](https://github.com/Jimbly/node-http-proxy/commit/058182ae832a1a8e018570123db24348009e8598), but it didn't help too.

P.P.S This leak starts reproducing when I have big enough rps - about 100-300 requests per second
P.P.P.S also tried to switch `keepAlive` option to `false` - it did not help too

Here is an example of my ws-proxy:

```
import Proxy from "http-proxy";
import http from "http";
import type { IncomingMessage, ClientRequest } from "http";

function create(): Proxy {
    const agent = new http.Agent({
        keepAlive: true,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        scheduling: "fifo",
        maxFreeSockets: 10,
        timeout: 300 * 1000
    });

    const proxy = Proxy.createProxyServer({ timeout: 300 * 1000, proxyTimeout: 300 * 1000, agent });

    function proxyReqHandler(proxyReq: ClientRequest, req: IncomingMessage): void {
        proxyReq.setHeader("Content-Type", req.headers["content-type"] || "plain/text");
    }
    proxy.on("proxyReq", proxyReqHandler);

    return proxy;
}

export function proxyWs(urlPath: string) {
    const proxy = create();

    return function (req, socket, upgradeHead, params) {
        

        const targetUrl = ... // some logic to create target url
        const socketFd = (socket as any)?._handle?.fd; // https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1312

        proxy.ws(req, socket, upgradeHead, { target: targetUrl, ignorePath: true }, err => {
            tracer.error(`error: ${err.message}`);
        });
    };
}
```

**UPD**
I added some logs and I see that `end` event on hanged sockets was not called. So it seems like client didn't send close event and sockets are hanged, but I expected, that theese sockets would be killed by timeout. Maybe you have any ideas why socket timeout is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Check first if this is related to [`http-party/node-http-proxy` issue 1510](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy/issues/1510) which states:

> I have encountered a problem of file descriptor leakage. When the browser is forced to close after establishing multiple websocket connections, the number of file descriptors of the agent program will not decrease. Through the windows resource monitor, you can see that there are a large number of `File \Device\Afd` in the handles associated with the agent.
>
> In [the source code](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy/blob/9b96cd725127a024dabebec6c7ea8c807272223d/lib/http-proxy/passes/ws-incoming.js#L128-L133), when an error occurs in the socket from the client to the proxy, the code executes `proxySocket.end()`, the code is as follows:
>
> ```
> // http-proxy/passes/ws-incoming.js:131
> socket.on('error', function (err) {
>    proxySocket.end();
> });
> ```
>
> The problem disappeared when I changed `proxySocket.end()` to `proxySocket.destroy()`.
>
> Excuse me, if you execute `proxySocket.destroy()`, will there be any other consequences?

Note that [`Jimbly/node-http-proxy` `lib/http-proxy/passes/ws-incoming.js`](https://github.com/Jimbly/node-http-proxy/blob/058182ae832a1a8e018570123db24348009e8598/lib/http-proxy/passes/ws-incoming.js#L128-L133) has the same code.

---

> Good call, thank you. I added this logic to my http-proxy fork, so now it includes these two fixes: [`Jimbly/node-http-proxy` commit 058182a](https://github.com/Jimbly/node-http-proxy/commit/058182ae832a1a8e018570123db24348009e8598) and [`http-party/node-http-proxy` issue 1510](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy/issues/1510), but I still have the porblem. Node version 18.12.1.

To debug the file descriptor leak issue in your WebSocket proxy setup with Node.js, you can try and add debug statements to track the lifecycle of sockets and requests. That would help identify where and when resources are not being released as expected.

- Track the creation, usage, and closure of sockets and requests, to understand the flow and pinpoint where leaks might be occurring.
- Keep a record of all open sockets and their states. That can be done by maintaining a global set or map.
- Regularly log the count of open sockets and requests. That will help you observe the trend over time, especially under load.
- Specifically log how errors are handled, as improperly handled errors can lead to resource leaks.

For instance, those debug statements could be:

```js
// Global set to keep track of open sockets
const openSockets = new Set();

function create(): Proxy {
    // existing code 

    // Log socket creation and closure
    proxy.on('open', function (proxySocket) {
        console.log(`Socket opened: ${proxySocket}`);
        openSockets.add(proxySocket);
        proxySocket.on('close', () => {
            console.log(`Socket closed: ${proxySocket}`);
            openSockets.delete(proxySocket);
        });
    });

    // Log request and response lifecycle
    proxy.on('proxyReq', function (proxyReq, req, res, options) {
        console.log(`Proxying request: ${req.url}`);
    });
    proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
        console.log(`Received response for: ${req.url}`);
    });

    // Log error handling
    proxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
        console.log(`Error in proxy: ${err.message}`);
    });

    return proxy;
}

// Regularly log the count of open sockets
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`Open sockets count: ${openSockets.size}`);
}, 10000); // Adjust the interval as needed

// rest of your code
```

Look for patterns or anomalies, such as sockets not closing when expected or errors that are not handled properly.

---

> I added some logs and I see that end event on hanged sockets was not called. So it seems like client didn't send close event and sockets are hanged, but I expected, that theese sockets would be killed by timeout. Maybe you have any ideas why socket timeout is not working?

In your update, you expected the sockets to be killed by a timeout. That implies the need to make sure the socket timeout is properly set in your code. The Node.js method `socket.setTimeout()` is key.

Since you observed that the end event on hanged sockets was not called, it is important to check if you have a listener for the `'timeout'` event on the socket. That listener should handle the closure of the socket when a timeout occurs.

Your expectation of socket termination might be based on an understanding of HTTP request timeouts, which can differ from socket connection timeouts. It is important to set the timeout on the socket itself, not just on the HTTP request.

If you are using keep-alive connections, the timeout behavior might only apply to the idle time between requests, not the total connection duration. That could explain why sockets are not timing out as expected.

Since you mentioned that the client did not send a close event, this might indicate client-specific behavior affecting the socket's lifecycle.

Make sure your socket timeout configuration is correctly implemented and that you have a good strategy for handling timeouts, especially in the context of keep-alive connections and varied client behaviors.

Comment: Good call, thank you. I added this logic to my http-proxy fork, so now it includes these two fixes: https://github.com/Jimbly/node-http-proxy/commit/058182ae832a1a8e018570123db24348009e8598, https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy/issues/1510, but I still have the porblem. Node version 18.12.1

Comment: @RostislavShtanko OK. I have edited the answer to include some debug ideas.

Comment: Thank you, good idea with a set, I'll try it.

Also, I added handler to proxy.close: https://gist.github.com/rostik404/6aad0b493bde0f6384c5770118db1933
And here I'm getting a lot of logs like `Closing proxy socket with fd undefined`. Could it be because of http-proxy tries to close leaked socket?

Comment: @RostislavShtanko I have edited the answer to add to your update.

Comment: I added timeout to http-agent, It should be passed to socket and it has been passed - I see it, when logging socket.timeout value. But to be shure that timeout has been passed, I added socket.setTimeout(300000) after socket creation. But it didn't help.
After that, I created collection with sockets and started to call socket.destroy() by myself for hanged sockets after timeout exceeded. It helped for sockets for which the end event was not called. But according to the logs, I still have sockets for which end and close events were called, but these sockets are still alive in OS for my process.

Comment: @RostislavShtanko OK, Check if sockets are somehow being duplicated or if references are held elsewhere in your code, preventing them from being garbage collected. There might be a delay in garbage collection in Node.js, causing sockets to appear open in the OS even after they are closed in Node.js. Monitoring garbage collection or forcing it (for debugging purposes) might give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the description above lacks how the websocket actually is being used so that I can provide a wild guess only, but since you mentioned keep alive…

There might be an issue with detecting dead clients? On WebSockets you‘ll need some form of idle ping messages so that some packets are exchanged allowing detecting dead clients even if the application has nothing to say. E.g. protocols like MQTT over websockets or sock.js have stuff like that build in.

If your usage has no such idle pings you are relying on TCP keep alive messaging, which according to https://serverfault.com/questions/735515/tcp-timeout-for-established-connections-in-windows/735768#735768 on Windows by default detects the dead client after 2 hours. (Most Linuxes have it even disabled by default.)

Notice, the agent keepAliveMsecs seems to take effect only after the first request, see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/41965.

You could try configuring a very low keep alive of say 30s at the OS level to see if that has an effect. Then if that helps consider implementing a ping-pong handshake message.